# How to create a directional line on google maps streetview?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I want to create a directional line like this:

[image]

You can see it in action in this link:  https://nightwalk.withgoogle.com/

I have been reading all the documentation of Google maps API but I could not find nothing about it. In google I only could find this another example where the line is used again.

https://hiroshima-welcome.jp/kanpai/catstreetview/index_2_on.html

Any idea about how to do it ?